# Typo3 can't get values from DataBase

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, extbase

Typo3 10.4
I created Models, Repositories and Controller. Values are getting written from the backend into the database but I can't get a bunch of values to the frontend. It's not all values that don't work but some.

```php
class Element extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{
    protected $type = "";
    protected $name = "";
    protected $beschreibung = "";
    protected $customRender = "";
    protected $mehrHtml = "";
    protected $formsUsingThisElement = "";

    public function __construct(string $type='', string $name='', string $beschreibung = '', string $customRender = '') {
        $this->setType($type);
        $this->setName($name);
        $this->setBeschreibung($beschreibung);
        $this->setCustomRender($customRender);
    }

    public function setType(string $type):void {
        $this->type = $type;
    }
    public function getType():string {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setName(string $name):void {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName():string {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setBeschreibung(string $beschreibung):void {
        $this->beschreibung = $beschreibung;
    }
    public function getBeschreibung():string {
        return $this->beschreibung;
    }

    public function setCustomRender(string $customRender):void {
        $this->customRender = $customRender;
    }
    public function getCustomRender():string {
        return $this->customRender;
    }

    public function setMehrHtml(string $mehrHtml) {
        $this->mehrHtml = $mehrHtml;
    }
    public function getMehrHtml() {
        return $this->mehrHtml;
    }

    public function setFormsUsingThisElement(string $formsUsingThisElement):void {
        $this->formsUsingThisElement = $formsUsingThisElement;
    }
    public function getFormsUsingThisElement(): string {
        return $this->formsUsingThisElement;
    }
}
```

Both $mehrHtml and $customRender actually have values but I can only get the other variables from the database.
While $type is of type select, $name and $beschreibung are of types input the two variables which I can not get the value of are config.type='text' in the TCA. But that shouldn't matter as I got another model which holds a text which is readable but an integer which I, too, can not get the value.

[image]

---

**EDIT**
Thomas remarked that the TCA might be misconfigured. Indeed were the columns in the Database in lowerCamelCase instead of snake_case which is why I didn't get any values from the database.

```php
return [
    'ctrl' => [
        //... ,
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'default_options' => [ //IMPORTANT HERE. snake_case instead of camelCase like in variable names.
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Standardangaben',
            'config' => [
                //....
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Mostly it's a misconfigured TCA when there is no output of the values. Did you check for typos? How does your SQL file look like?

Comment: If it was a misconfigured TCA wouldn't it fail to write the values to the database?
I checked the database manually and the values are correct.

Comment: Do you use manual mapping from Extbase variables to DB fields? If not, do you name the DB fields with underscores e.g. `custom_render` for Extbase `customRender`?

Comment: Thank you @ThomasLöffler for making me feel unbelievably dumb! I haven't realized that this was the error. I completely forgot. Thanks. A lot.